# Image sharing on Whatsapp in Ionic Framework on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, whatsapp

I am using https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin for Social Sharing on Ionic Framework.

The below code shares the image with a text and a link ,it works very fine for Android on whatsapp but when it comes to iOS only text is shared instead of image on whatsapp. This is the code below :

```
$scope.myCardShare=function (){

var message="My Message";
var subject="My Subject";
var file="www/"+$scope.finalImage; //My image location
var link="https://google.com"; //Link
console.log(file);
$cordovaSocialSharing
.share(message, subject, file, link) // Share via native share sheet
.then(function(result) {
// Success!
}, function(err) {
// An error occured. Show a message to the user
});
}
```

Please help

Comment: Could you make the question a bit more specific? This looks a bit like 'Can you finish my homework?' to me.

Comment: Done, can you check and suggest

Answer (score 4):

Hey I am running into the same problem too. I realize that if both "message" and "files" field are present, whatsapp will only share the text but not the file. When I remove the "message" field, the image got sent.

Why don't you try checking the platform by ionic.Platform.isIOS() and remove the "message" field if it's ios?

```
var message="My Message";
var subject="My Subject";
var file="www/"+$scope.finalImage; //My image location
var link="https://google.com"; //Link
console.log(file);
if(ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
    $cordovaSocialSharing
      .share(null, null, file, link) // Share via native share sheet
      .then(function(result) {
              // Success!
      }, function(err) {
              // An error occured. Show a message to the user
      });
} else {
    $cordovaSocialSharing
      .share(message, subject, file, link) // Share via native share sheet
      .then(function(result) {
              // Success!
      }, function(err) {
              // An error occured. Show a message to the user
      });
  }
```

Comment: In iOS image file and link are not sharing together it share only link - it removes the image we share.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$scope.myCardShare=function (){

var message="My Message";
var subject="My Subject";
var file="www/"+$scope.finalImage; //My image location
var link="https://google.com"; //Link
console.log(file);
$cordovaSocialSharing
.share(null, subject, file, message + '\n' + link) // Share via native share sheet
.then(function(result) {
// Success!
}, function(err) {
// An error occured. Show a message to the user
});
}
```

The whatsapp share will check if message is null, if it is null will send image with url, and this url will contains the message and the url.